Find integers $l,m,n$ satisfying $\{\frac{3^{l}}{10^4}\}=\{\frac{3^{m}}{10^4}\}=\{\frac{3^{n}}{10^4}\}$ where $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part.
This question is from a JEE reference book and I have absolutely zero clue on how to even begin:

Let the three sides of a triangle be integers $\ell,m,n$ respectively satisfying $\ell>m>n$ and $$
\left\{\frac{3^{\ell}}{10^4}\right\}=\left\{\frac{3^{m}}{10^4}\right\}=\left\{\frac{3^{n}}{10^4}\right\}
$$
where
$\left\{x\right\}= x - \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ and $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ denotes the integral
part of the number. Find the minimum perimeter of such a triangle.


The only thing I can figure out is that the task is to identify three distinct powers of $3$ that share the same last four digits.
Yeah, that's pretty much it: A google search gave no answers and so I'm here.
The answer given is even more intriguing — $\bf\mbox{a massive}\ 3003$ — which further diminishes my confidence in solving it.

Honestly, I’ve started to question the credibility of the problem itself as I don't really see a way to progress except for use of calculators.

@AmrutAyan yeah well, that is quite obvious since l,m,n are sides of a triangle.

Please do not answer in the comments, @CalvinLin.

@Shaun It was only a sketch, where OP has to work out the details. To confirm, is that not allowed, as part of getting OP to show their work? Otherwise, there isn't enough here to justify Quality Standards so this should be closed.

It varies, @CalvinLin.

@Shaun  Are you able to clarify what it varies on? Or is there a meta post which lays out this policy? Otherwise, there will be a concern that the individual (whether it's OP or the hinter) might feel targeted. $\quad$ This is the first time I've been told not to provide a hint in the comments, to the extent of having it deleted, so I'm trying to understand what is ideal behavior is.

It depends, in my view, on how much is revealed in the hint, @CalvinLin; at lot of the time, it's a judgement call.

One way to prove that $500$ is the minimal increment involves using the Binomial Theorem.
Evidently the increment must be a multiple of $4$, as only exponents divisible by $4$ give powers of $3$ that are $\equiv1\bmod10$. So we render
$3^{4k}=(1+80)^k\equiv1+80k+80^2\left(\dfrac{k(k-1)}2\right)+80^3\left(\dfrac{k(k-1)(k-2)}6\right)\equiv1\bmod10000,$
where only terms with nonzero residues $\bmod10000$ are included (the fraction $80^4/24$ has exponents of both $2$ and $5$ being $\ge4$ in its prime factorization).
We subtract $1$, multiply by $3$ to get all the coefficients as whole numbers and simplify to get
$240k+9600k(k-1)+6000k(k-1)(k-2)\equiv0\bmod10000$
$6000k^3-8400k^2-7360k\equiv0\bmod10000$
Divide by $80$ which also divides the modulus, so the modulus is also divided by $80$:
$75k^3-105k^2-902k=k(75k^2-105k-902)\equiv0\bmod125$
This has a root $k\equiv0\bmod125$, but the discriminant of the remaining quadratic factor evidently has a factor $\equiv3\bmod5$ and cannot have any square roots $\bmod125$. So $k\equiv0\bmod125$ is the only root and the increment $4k$ must be a multiple of $500$.

Oscar, thank you for this solution. Please forgive me for the silly question (I am not a mathematician). From $3^{4k} = 1 + 80,k \times (...)$, it seems to follow that $3^{4k} = 1,$mod$,80,k$. Could you please explain to me why it is also true that  $3^{4k} = 1,$mod$,10000;$?

I am solving for $3^k\equiv1\bmod10000$, since the problem statement requires that. I then find this is solvrd only for $k\equiv1\bmod125$ which the Carmichael function identifies as the minimal solution set.

Side note: Typically the way I see this done (via Binomial Theorem) is inductively to show that the order of 3 mod 10, 100, 10000, 10000 is 4, 20, 100, 500. In this way, you're just solving linear equations at each step so it's much simpler.   $\quad$ The quick alternative, of course, is to use Lifting the Exponent lemma, but that might be more power than the JEE asks for.

@OscarLanzi Understood. Thanks fpr the explanation.

The solution is pretty detailed and I understand almost every aspect of it except for the fact that why do we search only for $k$ such that $3^{k}\equiv1\bmod10000$? May be a silly question for you, but this is way beyond my scope and its just that I'm somewhat interested.

@dev You need $3^l$ and $3^m$ to differ by a multiple of $10000$ in order for their quotients to still differ by an integer when divided by $10000$. The OP seems to recognize this, so I proceeded from there.

NOTE: This solution is not completely valid, as I assumed that the Carmichael function is the same as that of the order to be computed. As pointed out by @CalvinLin in the comments, what we want is the order of $3 \mod 10000$, the Carmichael function computes the minimum number such that $a^k \equiv 1 \mod 10000 \forall (a,10000)=1$. In this specific case, the value of the Carmichael function is the same as that of the order of $3 \mod 10000$. A proof follows by checking $3^{\frac{\lambda(n)}{p}} \forall p | \lambda(n)$.
Using the Carmichael function, you find that the least value such that $3^n \equiv 1 \mod 10^4$ is $500$.  From there, notice that the only way to end for it in 0001 i.e. 1 is by adding $500$ to $n$, giving us $(500,1000,1500)$. But this does not satisfy the triangle inequality, so we use $n=501$ instead. This gives us the smallest possible values, $(501, 1001, 1501)$, and thus, the answer is $3003$.

Minor quip: why didn't you try $(1,501,1001)$? I know it doesn't satisfy triangle inequality, but it's a smaller example than the ones you started with.

-1 Note that you actually do NOT want the Carmichael function, but need to calculate the order of 3 mod 1000. EG If 3 was replaced with 1, then clearly $(l,m,n) = (2, 3, 4)$ would satisfy the conditions.

@Pranay good point, didn't notice that specific solution

@CalvinLin good point, but in this case it works out I think? I believe for $a$ coprime to $n$ the Carmichael function is the same as the order of $a \mod n$? Anyhow I will edit my answer to add this order point.

@Kraken Well, for example, $9$ is still coprime to $10^4$, but the order of $9$ modulo $10^4$ is not $500$ but $250$, because $9^{250} = 3^{500}$.

@MishaLavrov But how does one then know when the order of $a \mod n$ is the same as $\lambda(n)$?

@Kraken Check out primitive element. Essentially you have to calculate it out by checking $ a^ { \lambda(n) /p }$ for all $ p \mid \lambda(n)$.   $\quad$ (As an aside, my personal opinion is that you should state upfront that this isn't a valid solution. Otherwise, people who only read the start might perpetuate the misconception.)

Alright, I'll add that, @CalvinLin
